# How do you add execute permissions to a USB Flash Drive?

Tags: execute-command

So for the longest time I've been trying to get Steam to a be a fully functional program on my Chromebook 14 and I've gotten pretty close. I unfortunately ran out of space however and decided to buy a USB 3.0 Flash Drive and added a SteamLibrary folder to it but I can't use it because the "file system needs execute permissions". I've tried unmounting it and re mounting manually and using chmod and so far nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

With the USB drive mounted, type `mount` in a terminal window. Find the line referring to your USB drive. On my Ubuntu 14.04.4, and with a DIFFERENT USB drive, the line I found is:

```
/dev/sdc1 on /media/w3/ADATA UFD type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1003,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
#^device     ^mountpoint              ^filesystemtype     ^options
```

Note: You will NOT see the same values, but the ones your system tells you are the right ones.

Now it's time to read and re-read `man 8 mount` and decide which options you need to change, then do (adjusted for your options, device name, mount point):

```
# no changes
OPTIONS="rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1003,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2"
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 -t vfat -o remount,$OPTIONS /media/w3/ADATA\ UFD
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little new to Linux and honestly don't have a great idea on how to do that and don't have a lot of time to read 1000 lines of a manual. If there's any chance I could ask you to possibly shorten the process a bit I'd be very happy

Comment: No. RTFM. There is no other way.